# How to draw lines using Polyline and use coordinates from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, polyline, folium

I am trying to plot a map using folium and I was able to mark the coordinates with folium.Marker. Now I want to draw lines between each set of coordinates. I tried with folium.PolyLine with lamda and also with for loop. However, I am getting errors in both methods.

This is a sample dataframe :I want to draw a line for each row connecting Pickup coordinates to delivery coordinates.

```
Order_Nu   Pickup_Lat   Pickup_lng  Del_Lat      Del_lng
```

0   3491865     41.95586    -79.98764   40.39827    -75.94362
1   3478258     40.04115    -75.48032   41.09181    -75.34138
2   3469212     40.18448    -79.07961   40.11679    -75.01276

Method 01:

```
df_filtered_all.apply(lambda row:folium.PolyLine(locations=[ [row['Pickup_Lat'], 
                                                     row['Pickup_lng']]
                                                     , [row['Del_Lat']
                                                     , row['Del_lng']] ]
                                         , color='red') 
                                                                                
                                        ) .add_to(m)
```

Error:

--> 354             raise KeyError(key)
355         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
356

KeyError: 'Pickup_Lat'

Method 02:

```
for row in df_filtered_all.itertuples(index = True, name ='Pandas'):

       folium.PolyLine([[getattr(row, "Pickup_Lat"), getattr(row, "Pickup_lng")] ,
                 [getattr(row, "Del_Lat"), getattr(row, "Del_lng")] ]  ).add_to(m)
```

Error:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `KeyError: 'Pickup_Lat'` is saying that row doesn't have an entry called `'Pickup_Lat'`. If you do something like `df_filtered_all.apply(lambda row: print(row))` what does it print?

Comment: Thank you @Kaia, I found the issue. The coordinates were in the data frame as Object data type. I was able to use them as it is with folium.Marker, but when I used it with folium.Polyline it gave those errors. Once I changed the data type to float, it worked without any errors. Below is the code. Thanks again..!

for _, row in df_a.iterrows():   
    folium.PolyLine([[row['Pickup_Lat'], row['Pickup_lng']], 
                     [row['Del_Lat'], row['Del_lng']]]).add_to(map_osm_filtered)